# How to handle multiple currency in Paypal ecommerce website?

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-sandbox

My situation is below:

I am setting up an ecommerce website which sells clothes online. The website targets customers from US and Canada.I use Paypal as the payment company.

I will be setting up a Canadian bank account (I am from Canada) to link with Paypal to get the payments.

I am setting USD as the standard currency for both US and Canadian customers, so anyone visiting the website will see the price of products in USD only.

My question is : When a buyer from Canada tries to Pay by logging into Paypal, will he be able to see and pay the amount in Canadian dollars?

What will be the best approach in this?

Answer (score 1):

In My Experience, when purchasing goods from the US (I live in Australia) PayPal automatically converts the currency to AUD for me. I also believe that you can change the currency at the check out. In the past i have also been given the option (when sending money to foreign friends) to choose whether to allow PayPal or my bank to handle the currency conversion. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is : When a buyer from Canada tries to Pay by logging into Paypal, will he be able to see and pay the amount in Canadian dollars?

They will not be able to see in Canadian Dollars. They will be seeing only USD.

> What will be the best approach in this?

You can issue an Invoice with Canadian Dollars and equivalent USD they paid.